# ¿Como utilizar multiples passport de autenticacion en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, autenticación, passport

el el archivo auth.php tengo el siguiente código

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'apidriver' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'drivers',
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'drivers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Driver::class,
    ],

],
```

y este es el codigo de autenticacion para el controlador driver

```
if (Auth::guard('apidriver')->attempt(['email'=>request('email'),'password'=>request('password')])) {
  $driver=Auth::guard('apidriver')->user();
  $success['token'] =  $driver->createToken('Pizza App')->accessToken;
  return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
}else{
  return response()->json(['errorrr'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
  }
```

y me genera el siguiente error a la hora de acceder

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt()

En cuando al usuario el codigo de autenticación  me esta funcionando correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Modifica 'drivers' por 'apidriver' en providers y prueba. suerte...

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'apidriver' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Driver::class,
    ],

],
```

Comment: No,no me funciono la verdad llevo bastante tiempo tratando de solucionar el problema pero aún no he podido.